# Maximise columns and rows from a binary matrix

Tags: r, subset

I have a logical matrix and I want to find what is the maximum number of rows and columns that are all TRUE. That is I want to have the largest number of TRUE's per row for the most number of columns.

Here is some example data

```
a = c(T, T, T, T, T)
b = c(F, T, T, T, F)
c = c(F, F, T, T, F)
d = c(T, T, T, F, F)

x = matrix(c(a, b, c, d), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Which looks like this:

```
> x
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

In this example there are three solutions, which is a possibility. 
I could keep `x[c(1,2,4), 2:3]`, `x[1:3,3:4]`, and `x[1:2,2:3]` two of which give 3 rows and two columns, and one which gives 2 rows and 3 columns - all give a total of 6 TRUE's.

How could I figure this out so that it could scale to a much larger matrix?

I don't think I am communicating this problem very well - but also can't figure out how to phrase it better, so please ask for clarifications.

Comment: `x[1:2,2:4]` gives also 6. Answer should include such case?

Comment: Ah - yes good spot. It should also include this. I will make an edit.

Comment: I wonder if it's just a coincidence that all of the solutions for the matrix you gave include row 1 and column 3 which are all `TRUE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Please check and let me know :)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtools)

find_complete <- function(mat, n_row, n_col) {

  combinations(nrow(mat), n_row) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    rename_all(~str_replace(.x, 'V', 'r')) %>%
    crossing(.,
      combinations(ncol(mat), n_col) %>%
        as_tibble() %>%
        rename_all(~str_replace(.x, 'V', 'c'))
    ) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    gather(key, val, -rn) %>%
    mutate(key = key %>% str_remove('\\d')) %>%
    group_by(rn, key) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(data = map_chr(data, ~str_c(.x$val, collapse = ','))) %>%
    spread(key, data) %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    mutate(check = pmap_lgl(., function(...) {
      r_ind = str_split(..2, pattern = ',')[[1]] %>% as.numeric()
      c_ind = str_split(..1, pattern = ',')[[1]] %>% as.numeric()
      mat[r_ind, c_ind] %>% sum() == n_row * n_col
    })) %>%
    filter(check == TRUE) %>%
    select(-check) %>%
    rename_at(1:2, ~c('col_ind', 'row_ind'))

}

maximise <- function(mat) {

  best <- NULL

  to_check <-
    crossing(
      r = 1:nrow(mat),
      c = 1:ncol(mat)
    ) %>%
    mutate(s = r * c) %>%
    arrange(s) %>%
    as.data.frame()

  for (i in 1:nrow(to_check)) {
    temp <- find_complete(mat, to_check[i, 1], to_check[i, 2])
    if (temp %>% nrow() != 0) {
      if (i > 1) {
        if (to_check[i, 3] == to_check[i-1, 3]) {
          best <- bind_rows(best, temp)
        } else {
          best <- temp
        }
      } 
    } else {
      return(best)
    }
  }

}

maximise(x)
```

Comment: Hi Pawel, this gives the correct solution, but when I run it on my larger matrix, it is very slow. Any ideas on what might speed things up?

Comment: If, for example, you are interested only in a larger number of TRUE's you can change `crossing(
      r = 1:nrow(mat),
      c = 1:ncol(mat)
    )` to `crossing(
      r = 4:nrow(mat),
      c = 4:ncol(mat)
    )` for example. Or maybe it will be more efficient to start from the other side... Because there's a smaller number of combinations. I must think it through.